# How can we seamlessly implement a blocking process in generic code?

Tags: python

How can I create a class, that starts a blocking process in the background without needing to specifically design consumers/peers of that class around asyncio/threading? For example, how can we start a websocket connection to run alongside an event-loop, without specific support for threading/asyncio in the event-loop?

Comment: Use async operations instead of threads, especially for IO operations

Comment: Potentially just use https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY

Comment: pretty sure that async requires that the parent be specifically designed to support async. This is an option, but I want to avoid it.

Comment: Why? If you don't use async you'll block a thread only to wait for an IO operation to complete. The websockets documentation itself uses `async` in the Getting Started docs. Blocked threads are expensive - either they use spinlocks to avoid getting evicted from the CPU (thus wasting an entire core), or have to wait to be rescheduled and have their stack frames reloaded.

Comment: I have a basic working async solution, but I do not like that my pub/sub system needs to do extra preparation for the blocking processes. Ideally, the blocking processes would implement their own non-blocking solution; I want my pub/sub system to only be concerned with receiving and distributing messages. I will edit my question to present this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the conflict by automatically starting a `threading.Thread` on object creation. The thread will run blocking-processes without interruption, and can reference the `self` of its parent. This allows me to wrap any blocking process into a supporting object, avoiding the need to specifically design around the implementation of said process.

An example is provided below. On creation, the blocking process `self.process` will start on a separate thread, allowing the main thread to continue operation.

```
class SmartThread(threading.Thread):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(target=self.process)
        self.start()
    
    def process(self):
        while True:
            print(self.clock)
            time.sleep(1)
    
    @property
    def clock(self):
        return time.time()
```